# Mediaplayer won't quit

Tags: android, audio, path, media-player

In my onCreate method i check to see whether a media player is playing and if it is a shut it down

```
if(mediaplayer.isPlaying()==false)
     try {
         playAudio(path);
  } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();

}else{
    mediaplayer.stop();
    mediaplayer.reset();

}
    primarySeekBarProgressUpdater();

}
```

my play audio method is

```
 private void playAudio(String url) throws Exception{



  mediaplayer.setDataSource(url);
  mediaplayer.prepare();
  mediaplayer.start();

 }
```

i also initialize my media player before the onCreate method.  The problem is my media player won't shut down instead when a user clicks on a new song in the list view class it creates this class and plays both media players at the same time the old one continues playing.

Comment: explain your screen transitions? from which activity to which activity? layout of each activity.

Comment: I have a listview full of songs and then it goes to a relative layout with the media player

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I assume you have a `ListActivity` with full of songs, and users click to any of those, it will move to a new `Activity` to play the song, in which the song information is passed through the `Intent`.

First of all, you need to read and remember `Activity Lifecycle`: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Secondly, to your problem, according to the lifecycle, everytime users click to a song on the list, then it will create a new `Activity` to play the song, that means it creates a new `MediaPlayer` object as well. Hence, you can see many songs playing as much as you select the songs from the list.
What you need to do is to handle the `MediaPlayer` object when you close the music-playing screen to return to your song list.

```
MediaPlayer mPlayer = null;;

public void onCreate() {
    // init mediaplayer here
    mPlayer = ...
}


public void onDestroy() {
    // release object
    if( mPlayer != null ) {
        mPlayer.stop();
        mPlayer.release();
        mPlayer = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: But i want the media player to continue playing until the user picks a new song....   This will stop it while the user is trying to pick a new song .  how can i keep it playing while the user looks for a new song

Comment: then use `Service` which handles actions across multiple `Activity`

Comment: Can you explain i will give u the rep and check for answering..I am just a little confused on how to use the Service

Comment: make it another thread, I only answer according to the poster's question!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8276108/using-service-to-handle-actions-across-multiple-activities

Comment: I made a new thread check it out ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8276108/using-service-to-handle-actions-across-multiple-activities

Comment: Can u look at this thread and comment please thank you for the help    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8276381/media-service-activity