# Media Service Activity

Tags: android, service, path, android-intent, media-player

I have an activity that is a service which plays audio using a media player.  This is the service

```
class MusicService extends Service implements OnCompletionListener {
 MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

 @Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
return null;
}

 @Override
 public void onCreate() {
  mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.s);// raw/s.mp3
  mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
  mediaPlayer.start();
}
return START_STICKY;
 }

  public void onDestroy() {
   if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
  mediaPlayer.stop();
   }
   mediaPlayer.release();
 }

 public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer _mediaPlayer) {
stopSelf();
 }

}
```

Instead of playing from that raw file i want it to play from a path that is a String that comes from the sd card.  the path is held in the class that calls the service how do i pass that string to the service class and put it in the mediaplayer create method.  here is where i call the service

```
   private void playAudio(String url) throws Exception{
Intent music = new Intent(this,MusicService.class);
startService(music);
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [putExtra](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) commands of the starting Intent:

```
music.putExtra(key, value);
```

Then get that passed info in the [onStartCommand](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand%28android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int%29) of your mediaplayer service:

```
intent.getExtras().getString(key);
```

Beware that this intent can be null in cases when the service is restarted by the system.